# Customers also bought section in cart drawer

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to add "Customers also bought" section under the added items in the cart drawer. I'm doing that by checking for the tags that start with '__with', then getting their handle Now some tag products are duplicates of the ones already in the cart. How to remove duplicates?

I added this logic inside the `cart-drawer.liquid`.

```
          <div class="CartAddons">
            <div class="CartAddons__Heading">Customers also bought</div>

            {%- for item in cart.items -%}
                {%- assign tags = item.product.tags | join ' ' -%}
                {%- assign product_handle = tags | split: '__with:' | last -%}
                {%- assign associated_product = all_products[product_handle] -%}

               {%- if tags contains '__with' -%}
                  <div class="CartAddons__Section">
                      <div class="CartAddons__Item"> 
                        {% render 'product-item', product: associated_product, use_horizontal: true, show_labels: false, show_product_info: true, show_vendor: false, show_price_on_hover: true %}
                      </div>
                  </div>

               {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Need to develop such logic to check if a product is already in the cart.

```
{% assign productsInCart = cart.items | map: 'product_id' %}
```

and then make sure the tagged product is not into the cart items array

```
{% untill productsInCart contains associated_product.id %}{% endunless %}
```